# Connect Unix with SQL database and create employee table and insert data's

Tags: mysql, unix, database-connection

Connect Unix with SQL database and create employee table and insert data's and extract email column from employee table and check that email id is valid or not. I am new for Unix so please give solution guys.

Comment: a simple google  search might give you an answer

Comment: provide wht you have tried and maybe someone can help.